# How to reveal a file in vim Netrw treeview?

Tags: vim

How can I reveal a specific file (usually the current buffer) in `Netrw` tree view, similar to `:NERDTreeFind` command does for `NERDTree`?

To be more precise...

I have a file opened in a buffer and I use `:Expore` to open `netrw`.

I want the file I had in my active buffer to be shown in `netrw` (expand all directories from working dir to the file) so I can see all its sibling files and folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here goes a simple way to do it.
You can change `:Explore` command to `Vexplore`, `:Hexplore`, etc.

```
# show file in netrw
command! ExploreFind let @/=expand("%:t") | execute 'Explore' expand("%:h") | normal n

# or as a mapping
map <Leader>f :let @/=expand("%:t") <Bar> execute 'Explore' expand("%:h") <Bar> normal n<CR>
```

Here goes some explanation:

- `let @/=expand("%:t")` sets the last search to the current filename
- `execute 'Explore' expand("%:h")` open netrw passing the current file path as an argument, to make sure it list that directory
- `normal n` search for the filename in the directory listing

Got the idea from https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_for_current_word_in_new_window.

Note: This doesn't do exactly the same as `NERDTreeFind` because it won't show the whole directory tree but it is enough for my needs.

Comment: This does not work with (quite common) `set autochdir` since `%:h` is then expanded to just a dot `.` and misinterpreted by netrw. With `autochdir on` this works for me: `execute 'Explore '.fnamemodify('.', ':p')`

Comment: Btw. you can use `\|` instead of `<Bar>`s

Answer (score 2):

This version works in neovim (written in lua + vimscript) and behaves like "show in project view" in Jetbrains Idea IDE. I mean it looks like it starts from the root of a project (pwd) and open directories until your file.

```
vim.g.netrw_liststyle = 3
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>e', function ()
    local relative_path = vim.fn.expand("%:h")
    local startPos, endPos = string.find(relative_path, "/")
    if startPos == 1 then
       relative_path = "."
    end
    vim.cmd [[:let @/=expand("%:t")]]
    vim.cmd("Lexplore " .. relative_path)
    if startPos > 1 then
        while startPos ~= nil do
            startPos, endPos = string.find(relative_path, "/", endPos + 1)
            vim.cmd("call netrw#Call('NetrwBrowseUpDir', 1)")
        end
        vim.cmd("call netrw#Call('NetrwBrowseUpDir', 1)")
    end
    vim.cmd(":normal n<CR>zz")
end)
```